# Objective C UIAlertView queue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to show multiple messages on iOS one by one, but the problem is that showing UIAlertView is non-blocking. I tried to handle alert closing with `clickedButtonAtIndex` and show same alert inside. Here is some code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
...
@property UIAlertView *alert;
...
@end

...
[alert show]; //somewhere in code, starts chain of messages
...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Some changes in alert object
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: Do you have buttons for each/any of the alert views that a user can click to dismiss it, and if so, are you looking at remembering which button was clicked to dismiss a particular alert?

Comment: I would suggest that multiple sequential alerts is a less-than-ideal user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have one UIAlertView and change its message on button click...  Maybe increment its tag as well

try overriding

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex`

Comment: Ok, I recieve button click, then I change message, but then message disapeares!

Comment: It looks like there is no way to have the alertView remain up after a button is clicked, so in '-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex' you can show the alert again

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to set tags on the alert views:

```
#define ALERT_1   1
#define ALERT_2   2

...
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
alert.tag = ALERT_1;
[alert show]; //somewhere in code, starts chain of messages
...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag) {

        case ALERT_1: {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
            alert.tag = ALERT_2;
            [alert show];
        } break;

        case ALERT_2: {
           ....
        } break;
    }

}
```

This way you don't have to use variables for the alert views.

Answer (score 0):

You need one property for each alert view you want to show. In the delegate function check which one finished and start the next one:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
...
@property UIAlertView *alert1;
@property UIAlertView *alert2;
@property UIAlertView *alert3;

@end

...
alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
[alert1 show]; //somewhere in code, starts chain of messages
...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView == alert1) {
        alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
        [alert2 show];
    } else if (alertView == alert2) {
        alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
        [alert3 show];
    }

}
```

Comment: If the messages aren't completely static, an `NSMutableArray` of `UIAlertView`s might be more appropriate.